# Bootstrap 5 div with h-100 overflows parent row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.long-text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid rounded shadow bg-white border mb-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 p-0 me-2">
          <div id="carouselComponent" class="carousel slide h-100">
            <div class="carousel-inner rounded h-100">
              <div class="carousel-item h-100 active">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c8/a5/a8/c8a5a813afea19847217c765232b727d.jpg" class="d-block w-100 h-100 object-fit-cover" alt="...">
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselComponent" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselComponent" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col p-3">
          <div class="row">
            <h5 class="mb-1"><a>Red Keep</a></h5>
            <div class="text-truncate text-muted mb-1">
              <i class="fa fa-location-dot"></i> King's Landing
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="stackOverflowCom d-block d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-end h-100">
            <div>
              <div class="mb-2"><span class="badge bg-primary">0.0</span> <a href="#!" class="text-muted">(0 reviews)</a></div>
              <div class="long-text text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc lobortis metus quam, sodales eleifend mauris scelerisque non. Integer tincidunt turpis quis varius malesuada. Morbi efficitur pretium mauris vitae tempor. Praesent ultricies arcu eget sagittis malesuada. Vivamus viverra varius scelerisque. <br>
                Suspendisse eget suscipit nulla, at feugiat felis. Curabitur eleifend lectus metus, sit amet convallis neque rhoncus efficitur. Phasellus ullamcorper interdum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris sagittis felis tempus mauris venenatis pellentesque eget non augue. Aenean eu nisi faucibus, varius libero eget, vestibulum sem. Aliquam lacus est, vulputate ut ornare quis, blandit vel nisi. Cras rhoncus ante ipsum, sed sagittis risus aliquet eget.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <div class="row justify-content-end align-items-baseline d-md-block">
                <div class="col-4 col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-baseline">
                  <h3>10000$</h3>
                  <span>/day</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
                  <h6 class="text-decoration-line-through text-muted me-2">19999</h6>
                  <h6 class="text-success">-10%</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-grid">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Book</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/peppapig19/pen/KKGjBoK

on md+ screens the div with class `stackOverflowCom` overflows parent row when uses `h-100`. the reason why i need `h-100` in the first place, is i want to align everything except "Red Keep" and "King's Landing" to the bottom of the card. how can i achieve this?

any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `d-md-flex`, `flex-md-column`, and `justify-content-between` classes to the parent container.
`<div class="col d-md-flex flex-md-column justify-content-between p-3">`

Remove `h-100` and `justify-content-between` from the `stackOverflowCom` container as they are not needed (you may also want to remove `align-items-end`)

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.long-text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid rounded shadow bg-white border mb-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 p-0 me-2">
          <div id="carouselComponent" class="carousel slide h-100">
            <div class="carousel-inner rounded h-100">
              <div class="carousel-item h-100 active">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c8/a5/a8/c8a5a813afea19847217c765232b727d.jpg" class="d-block w-100 h-100 object-fit-cover" alt="...">
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselComponent" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselComponent" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-md-flex flex-md-column justify-content-between p-3">
          <div class="row">
            <h5 class="mb-1"><a>Red Keep</a></h5>
            <div class="text-truncate text-muted mb-1">
              <i class="fa fa-location-dot"></i> King's Landing
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="stackOverflowCom d-block d-md-flex align-items-end">
            <div>
              <div class="mb-2"><span class="badge bg-primary">0.0</span> <a href="#!" class="text-muted">(0 reviews)</a></div>
              <div class="long-text text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc lobortis metus quam, sodales eleifend mauris scelerisque non. Integer tincidunt turpis quis varius malesuada. Morbi efficitur pretium mauris vitae tempor. Praesent ultricies arcu eget sagittis malesuada. Vivamus viverra varius scelerisque. <br>
                Suspendisse eget suscipit nulla, at feugiat felis. Curabitur eleifend lectus metus, sit amet convallis neque rhoncus efficitur. Phasellus ullamcorper interdum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris sagittis felis tempus mauris venenatis pellentesque eget non augue. Aenean eu nisi faucibus, varius libero eget, vestibulum sem. Aliquam lacus est, vulputate ut ornare quis, blandit vel nisi. Cras rhoncus ante ipsum, sed sagittis risus aliquet eget.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <div class="row justify-content-end align-items-baseline d-md-block">
                <div class="col-4 col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-baseline">
                  <h3>10000$</h3>
                  <span>/day</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
                  <h6 class="text-decoration-line-through text-muted me-2">19999</h6>
                  <h6 class="text-success">-10%</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-grid">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Book</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```